# How to trigger OnMouseOver/OnMouseExit in a Unity test script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a script for my Unity game managing the hover state of the gameobject the script is attached to

```
public sealed class HoverStateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        UpdateEntityHoverState(true);
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        UpdateEntityHoverState(false);
    }

    private void UpdateHoverState(bool hovered)
    {
         // ... modify the state ...
    }
}
```

I know that I should not try to test private methods because there is no need for it, I can check the result of the public service ([Should I test private methods or only public ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones)).

The thing is that the logic in `UpdateHoverState` is testable very easily. So I could

- not test it, because it's private
- make the method public and test it, but access modifiers should be as limited as possible, so this breaks a convention ([Access Modifiers - what's the purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910085/access-modifiers-whats-the-purpose))
- perform a `OnMouseOver` and `OnMouseExit` by triggering something

I would prefer the last one but I don't know if Unity offers a way to trigger those methods. Is there a way to create a mock which calls them internally?

Comment: I am not sure but should it be tested as a unit test. Shouldn't it be part of UI test ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, have to read about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly `OnMouseOver()` is called in every frame you probably want to use `OnMouseEnter()` instead.

Unity's scripting is not pure OO feel free to violate laws whenever you feel like it needs to be. E.g. every Unity message can be `public, protected, private` etc. so you could just make the access modifier public and trigger it yourself.

Also you can use reflection to call private methods since you only want to test the `UpdateHoverState()` method's inner logic this might be better. However reflection is vulnerable to refactors (you need the name of the method in the form of a string). For accessing private methods via a cool extension method using reflection see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25415496/11124332).

And you can also use preprocessor symbols in order to make a method public when testing or to provide additional information about the class. [Unity preprocessors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

```cs
#if TESTING
// public wrapper method when testing
public void UpdateHoverStateTestHelper(bool hovered)
{
    UpdateHoverState(hovered);
}
#endif
void UpdateHoverState(bool hovered)
{
    // ... modify the state ...
}
```

```cs
#if TESTING || UNITY_EDITOR
// Now we will know the method name even when it gets renamed (using refactoring tools)
static readonly string UpdateHoverStateMethod = nameof(UpdateHoverState);
#endif
void UpdateHoverState(bool hovered)
{
    // ... modify the state ...
}
```

```cs
#if TESTING || UNITY_EDITOR
// nameof is accessed at compile time so the string can be const too
const string UpdateHoverStateMethod = nameof(UpdateHoverState);
#endif
void UpdateHoverState(bool hovered)
{
    // ... modify the state ...
}
```

The cool thing about these is that whenever you are building for your target platform these codes will be stripped (assuming you unset the `TESTING` preprocessor)

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. I think it's better to simply make the `On...` methods public and trigger them instead of creating a whole reflection logic .. :)

Comment: your welcome, yeah that might be the easiest way, no Unity developer gonna call an engine message directly in a game logic anyway